# Android newChooseAccountIntent disable new account option

Tags: android, android-intent, account

Is there anyway to disable the option to "Add Account" when using newChooseAccountIntent. I just want the user to pick from the accounts which already exist on the device. I don't want them to have the option to add an account.

Is there particular parameters I can pass to disable this, or is there another intent I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I did not find a way of doing this.